# How to center only one graph

Tags: beamer, forest

Let me start with an image..

[image]

Now, is it possible to center only the table and let the flowchart on the top corner?

Here is a **MWE**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{beamer}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[shrink=25]{Resultados - glioxal}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vspace{-0.5cm}\centering{
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Reacción problema}\label{table:reaccion_central}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\toprule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{Compuesto}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{RM1}                          \\ \midrule
                                     & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{COSMO}}$ &     $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{SS-COSMO}}$ \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
CC$_{\text{ref}}$                  &      -                   &    -                         \\ 
cis dihidro-dihidroxi                & I need                     &  to center                        \\ 
trans dihidro-dihidroxi              &  only                    & this table                             \\ 
&  &  \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
}\medbreak

\scalebox{0.6}{
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom     color=blue!20,
    edge+=->,
    l sep'+=10pt,
  }, 
   [This
     [is a forest]
     [flow
       [chart!]
     ]
   ] 
\end{forest}
}
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you desire by:

1. Turning off the `multicols` ;
2. Bringing the `forest` before the table (with a `\mbox{}\hfill` to right-justify); and
3. Increasing the "lift" of the table to `\vspace{-2.5cm}`

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{beamer}
   \usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
   \usepackage{multimedia}
   \usepackage{forest}
   \usepackage{float}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   %\setbeamercovered{transparent}
   \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
   \setbeamersize{text margin left=2em,text margin right=2em}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{frame}[shrink=25]{Resultados - glioxal}

   \mbox{}\hfill\scalebox{0.6}{
   \begin{forest}
       for tree={
           rounded corners, draw, align=center, top color=white, bottom     color=blue!20,
           edge+=->,
           l sep'+=10pt,
       }, 
        [This
            [is a forest]
            [flow
                [chart!]
            ]
        ] 
   \end{forest}
   }

   %\begin{multicols}{2}
   \vspace{-2.5cm}\centering{
   \begin{threeparttable}
   \caption{Reacción problema}\label{table:reaccion_central}
   \begin{tabular}{lcc}
   \toprule
           \multicolumn{1}{c}{Compuesto}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{RM1}                          \\ \midrule
                                                                            & $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{COSMO}}$ &     $\Delta G^\circ_{\text{SS-COSMO}}$ \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
   CC$_{\text{ref}}$                  &      -                   &    -                         \\ 
   cis dihidro-dihidroxi                & I need                     &  to center                        \\ 
   trans dihidro-dihidroxi              &  only                    & this table                             \\ 
   &  &  \\ 
   \end{tabular}
   \end{threeparttable}
   }\medbreak

   %\end{multicols}
   \end{frame}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image: This is what it looks like after the 3 small changes]